# oracle XMLTABLE is not working as expected

Tags: oracle, xpath, oracle11g, xmltable

I was using EXTRACT method to extract the values from XML type column in Oracle 11g database.

If my table has 10 rows,
as EXTRACT is used in the select clause, when i put some condition in XPATH like

```
'/Items/OperatingSystem/@Version[contains(.,"4.04")]'
```

In the returned rows, it shows the null if the XPATH expression is not matching, but it shows all 10 rows.

So I tried to moved to XMLTABLE as I found this is the latest (EXTRACT is deprecated) As we know it is used in FROM clause. I tried few basic queries and found it only return rows which has match with the XPATH expression.(skips the null rows returned in case of EXTRACT case)

One strange issue I found using XMLTABLE is -
In my local environment, when I use the XPATH expression

```
'/Items/OperatingSystem/@Version[contains(.,"4.04")]'
```

In result, it selects only the rows having Name containing 'Dee' in it.

But when I run the same query against our testing environments

It selects all the rows instead of only selecting having Name containing 'Dee'.
I could not find any hint why this is happening. I tried few more queries putting condition on other fields like Age etc.. but the result is same. It is returning all rows.

Here are the version details - 
Local Oracle Version -

```
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
"CORE   11.2.0.2.0  Production"
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
```

Testing Environment Oracle Version -

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
"CORE   11.2.0.3.0  Production"
TNS for HPUX: Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
```

Are there any changes related to XMLTABLE in these versions.

**Sample Data**

Suppose I have the following table

```
NAME    | XMLDATA       |   CRT_TS
Ubuntu  | UbuntuXMLDATA | 20-OCT-2016
Windows | WindowsXMLDATA| 20-OCT-2016
```

UbuntuXMLDATA

```
<Items>
<OperatingSystem Name="Ubuntu 12.04" Version="12.04" />
<OperatingSystem Name="Ubuntu 14.04" Version="14.04" />
<OperatingSystem Name="Ubuntu 16.04" Version="16.04" />
</Items>
```

WindowsXMLDATA

```
<Items>
<OperatingSystem Name="Windows" Version="8" />
<OperatingSystem Name="Windows" Version="7" />
</Items>
```

In table, above xmls are present in column XMLDATA.

**Query**

```
select Name,rx.COLUMN_VALUE as XPATH_OUTPUT from Operating_System, XMLTABLE('/Items/OperatingSystem/@Version[contains(.,"4.04")]' PASSING XMLTYPE(XMLDATA)) rx where CRT_TS = 20-OCT-2016;
```

**Expected Result**

```
Name    | XPATH_OUTPUT
Ubuntu  | 14.04
```

**Actual Result**

```
Name    | XPATH_OUTPUT
Ubuntu  | 12.04
Ubuntu  | 14.04
Ubuntu  | 16.04
```

The issue I am facing is the above query is working fine in my local database.
But against testing environment It is returning three rows instead of one. I am not able to figure out Why? Is is due to Oracle version (I have given the details above) mismatch?

Comment: Please post some sample data, a query and the unexpected result you are having

Comment: @Aleksej I have provided the sample data. Please see if you can help

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it is a bug or not. 
In xmltable if you aren't using alias for passing xml. ".' is root of xml.

Try this xpath.

`'/Items/OperatingSystem/@Version[contains(.,"4.04")]'`
`'/Items/OperatingSystem/@Version[contains(.,"OperatingSystem")]'`
`'/Items/OperatingSystem/@Version[contains(.,"Ubuntu")]'`

Result always will be. 3 rows.

contains(.,"xxxx")] Check if whole document contains string

Solution 1

Change xquery.

`'/Items/OperatingSystem[contains(@Version,"14.04")]/@Version'`

Solution 2

Add alias for xml. 
`XMLTABLE('$doc/Items/OperatingSystem/@Version[contains(.,"4.04")]' PASSING XMLTYPE(XMLDATA) as "doc")`

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing similar issue, I am able to fix the problem by changing the XPATH expression. Updated XPATH expression to

```
/Items/OperatingSystem[contains(@Version,"4.04")]/@Version
```

Instead of using dot(.) operator to get the value for current attribute, giving @Version itself.